# Inner class depending on a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, partial-specialization, pimpl-idiom

Consider next example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template< int N, typename T >
struct B
{
    struct C;
};

template< typename T >
struct B< 0, T >::C
{
    typedef T type;
};

template< int N, typename T >
struct B< N, T >::C
{
    typedef T type[N];
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"n=0   type = " << typeid( B< 0, float >::C::type ).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"n=5   type = " << typeid( B< 5, float >::C::type ).name() << std::endl;
}
```

When compiled using g++ (version 4.3.0)

```
g++ dfg.cpp  -ansi -pedantic -Wall
```

the compile error is :

```
dfg.cpp:13: error: qualified name does not name a class before ‘{’ token
dfg.cpp: In instantiation of ‘B<0, float>::C’:
dfg.cpp:25:   instantiated from here
dfg.cpp:20: error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array
```

What I am really trying to archive is to have different Imp implementation depending on the enum value (in the example, instead of an enum, I used int, but it shouldn't matter).

Can someone explain why is this not allowed?
Why am I getting the first error?
(this one : qualified name does not name a class before ‘{’ token)

---

Regarding the pimpl implementation depending on a template parameter, I created a new question (with better example) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425065/c-pimpl-idiom-implementation-depending-on-a-template-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define `C` outside `B` this way - `C` doesn't exist for the `B` specialization you're creating. If you want to specialize B::C, you need to specialize B. Are you trying to do the following?

```
template< int N, typename T >
struct B
{
    struct C {
        typedef T type[N];
    };
};

template< typename T >
struct B< 0, T >
{
    struct C {
        typedef T type;
    };
};
```

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
template< int N, typename T >
struct B
{
    struct C;
};

template< typename T >
struct B< 0, T > {
    struct C;
};

template< typename T >
struct B< 0, T >::C
{
    typedef T type;
};

template< int N, typename T >
struct B< N, T >::C
{
    typedef T type[N];
};
```

This partially specializes B for 0 and forward declares C, so that `B<0, T>::C` can be defined.

Comment: Not really. I am using the pimpl idiom, and trying to have different implementations of it depending on the template parameter. You can forward declare the struct C in struct B, and define it outside, but both have to be defined at the moment of the instantiation

Comment: VJo: There's no pImpl in your post... What I posted gives you `n=0 type=float` and `n=5 type=float [5]` - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The struct C emulates the pimpl idiom, because it is forward declared in the struct B. So, I have to declare the template specialization for struct B in order to have this working? Why it can't use the declaration of B it is there?

Comment: @VJo: There's nothing preventing you from e.g. creating a B specialization that doesn't have a `struct C` at all. So the compiler can't know that the specialization of `B` has a `C` member unless you tell it, by showing it the specialization.

Comment: Right, I will create new question

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid:

```
template< typename T >
struct B< 0, T >::C
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

You *can* specialize members of class templates, but only for implicit instantiations of those class templates. This means in plain English: Only if you give values for all the template arguments of the enclosing class template (whose member you need to specialize).

```
template< >
struct B< 0, int >::C
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

What you wrote is the definition of a `B<0, T>::C`, which is a member of a class template partial specialization of `B<N, T>`. Such a partial specialization does not exist, therefor, the compiler errored out.

---

You have several options to solve this. One is

```
template< int N, typename T >
struct B
{
    template<typename N1, typename T1>
    struct CMember { typedef T1 type[N1]; };

    template<typename T1>
    struct CMember<0, T1> { typedef T1 type; };

    struct C { 
      typedef typename CMember<N, T>::type type;
    };
};
```

Note that explicit specializations (non-partial) cannot be put into the class template directly (so, `template<> struct CMember<0, int> { ... }` would be ill-formed when writting inside the body of `B`). You would need to define the "selector" template outside `B` then (perhaps in a `detail` namespace).

Other alternatives include deriving from `CMember` and inheriting its typedefs.