# c++ pimpl idiom : Implementation depending on a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, partial-specialization, pimpl-idiom

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419670/inner-class-depending-on-a-template-argument) I unsuccessfully asked how to use different pimpl implementation depending on a template argument.

Maybe this example ilustrates better what I am trying to do :

```
#include <iostream>

template< int N, typename T >
struct B
{
    B() : c( new C< N > )
    {}

    template< int M >
    struct C;
    C< N > *c;
};

template< int N, typename T >
template< int M >
struct B< N, T >::C
{
    int a[M];
};

// version 1 that doesn't work    
    template< int N, typename T >
    template< >
    struct B< N, T >::C< 0 >
    {
        int a;
    };
// version 2 that doesn't work
    template< typename T >
    template< int M >
    struct B< 0, T >::C
    {
        int a;
    };


int main()
{
    B< 0, float >   b0;
    B< 1, int >     b1;

    std::cout << "b0 = " << sizeof(b0.c->a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b1 = " << sizeof(b1.c->a) << std::endl;
}
```

It still fails if I try to specialize the struct C (the above doesn't compile)

So, is it possible to do?

I know a work around like this :

```
template< int M >
struct D
{
  int a[M];
};
template<  >
struct D<0>
{
  int a;
};

template< int N, typename T >
template< int M >
struct B< N, T >::C
{
    D< M > helper;
};
```

but if possible, I would like to avoid it

Comment: Does the real definition of `B<N,T>::C<M>` use `N` and/or `T` at all?  If not, why should it be a member of class template `B`?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, it uses, but this example just simplifies the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not allowed by the language.

§ 14.7.3.16 (FCD 2010-03-26) states:

> In an explicit specialization
>   declaration for a member of a class
>   template or a member template that
>   appears in namespace scope, the member
>   template and some of its enclosing
>   class templates may remain
>   unspecialized, except that the
>   declaration shall not explicitly
>   specialize a class member template if
>   its enclosing class templates are not
>   explicitly specialized as well. In
>   such explicit specialization
>   declaration, the keyword template
>   followed by a template-parameter-list
>   shall be provided instead of the
>   template<> preceding the explicit
>   specialization declaration of the
>   member. The types of the
>   template-parameters in the
>   template-parameter-list shall be the
>   same as those specified in the primary
>   template definition.

```
[ Example:
template <class T1> class A {
    template<class T2> class B {
        template<class T3> void mf1(T3);
        void mf2();
    };
};
template <> template <class X>

class A<int>::B {
    template <class T> void mf1(T);
};
template <> template <> template<class T>
void A<int>::B<double>::mf1(T t) { }
template <class Y> template <>
void A<Y>::B<double>::mf2() { } // ill-formed; B<double> is specialized but
// its enclosing class template A is not
—end example ]
```

Comment: by the way, that is § 14.7.3.18 in the current c++ standard, and that paragraph answers my question. Thanks